# how to focus on google marker after clicking item from listview?

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, google-maps-api-3

```
This is my marker which is set in -  MainAcitivity 

 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759))
            .title("Store"));
```

And What i am Trying to do is that in listview when user will click on txtplace field so google marker will focus on that marker which i set

```
 holder.txtPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.txtStore.getText().toString().equals("Store") ) {
                //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(  what to do here ??? ));

            } 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function for example:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759)), 14));
```

Comment: it saying CameraUpdateFactory cannot be applied